# Error installing python pyzipcode

Tags: python, sqlite, pip, jupyter-notebook, installation-package

I am trying to install pyzipcode package using

```
pip install pyzipcode
```

I have a list of lat,lon data from which I require the Zipcodes. I checked online and pyzipcode came across as the most dependable solution for python. While trying to install I get the error below:

**In file included from src/module.c:24:0:
    src/connection.h:33:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.**
**error: command 'Anac\Scripts\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1**

Also there are other results with same errors but haven't found any solution from those.

P.S: Any other way to get ZIPCODES in python from lon,lat will be helpful in the meantime

Comment: @TrisNefzger Okay. Could you guide me to a place where I can find the precompiled version or may be how to go about finding a precompiled version.

Comment: @TrisNefzger : I am also getting the line below as error. I just saw this.       In file included from src/module.c:24:0:
    src/connection.h:33:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.    I thought sqlite comes along Python(2.5) onward. I am running python2.7

Comment: Suggest giving up on finding the precompiled version since pyzipcode just does lookups from a sqlite db built from a csv dating back to 2004. You could roll your own with a more recent zipcode csv from that can be downloaded from http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2014.html (Zip Code Tabulation Areas Gazateer File in which zipcodes are called GEOID), http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/, and http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/.

Comment: I got wierd errors trying to install pyzipcode too and it does not seem fruitful to continue the effort. There is a csv2sqlite conversion script at https://github.com/rgrp/csv2sqlite and a tutorial on using sqlite3 from python at http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when installing pyzipcode on EC2 linux. Solved the issue by `sudo yum install sqlite-devel` before `pip install pyzipcode==1.0`. On Ubuntu or other system, it could be `sudo apt-get install sqlite-dev` or so.

Answer (score 0):

From the error. It is expected to install **sqlite3** in the system.

## Install sqlite3 in ubuntu system with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

## In mac use brew:

```
brew install sqlite3
```

## In windows follow these steps:

1. Go to [SQLite3 download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) page, “Precompiled Binaries For Windows”
   section
2. Download “sqlite-shell” and “sqlite-dll” archive files
3. Unpack them and set environmental path (i.e., C:\program_files\sqlite3)
4. Install the sqlite3 Ruby gem.